# What would happen after I uninstall all my OS using OS-Uninstaller? Will I be able to boot from USB or CD so that I can make a fresh install of an OS?

Tags: installation, uninstall

What would happen after I uninstall **all** the OS using OS-Uninstaller? For more information about OS-Uninstaller, you can visit [the wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) and [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769489&p=10871988#post10871988)

Will I be able to **boot** from USB or CD so that I can make a fresh install of an OS? I wish to do it before doing a fresh install of an OS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All OS Uninstaller does is nuke disk partitions that it detects. It doesn't stop you booting to media like USB or CD... Assuming you don't nuke the USB partition.

And if you're just planning on wiping a disk down before installing Ubuntu, you can do all of that from inside the installer without needing to use third party software.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When you say " It doesn't stop you booting to media like USB or CD... Assuming you don't nuke the USB partition", do you mean formatting the USB where the OS I wish to install has been burnt?

Comment: I mean formatting the Live USB you'd be installing *from* (eg where you burnt the Ubuntu ISO).